# How to add label to the classification data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a data that has a shape of 100X3 where the first and second column are the x and y values of my plot and the third row contains 0 and 1 which I am using to classify the data. I plotted it using -

```
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],c=Y)
plt.xlabel('x 1')
plt.ylabel('x 2')
```

but I don't know how to add labels for the classification. So far this code classifies the data by using two different colours. I want to add labels which say that yellow dots belong to classification 0 and purple belong to 1. I will really appreciate if someone could please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a legend to show this using `plt.legend` or am I misunderstanding the question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a legend (see [matplotlib.pyplot.legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)), and split the X matrix up with respect to the categories of Y.

Here is [an example from the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html)

If you want a simpler solution, the code below should get you started.

```
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Random X Matrix for Demonstration
X = np.random.random((100,2))
## Generate Random Categories
Y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=(100,))
## Define a Color Palatte (alternative would be to define a list of colors)
##colors = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Spectral') ## For High Number of Categories
colors = ['r','g','b'] ## For low number of categories

## Loop Over Unique Categories in Y
for num, cat in enumerate(np.unique(Y)):
    ## Get indices for when Y is equal to cat
    ind = np.where(Y==cat)   
    ## Plot the data for that category only & assign a label 
    plt.scatter(X[ind,0],X[ind,1], c=colors[num], 
            label = 'Category {0}'.format(cat))
    ## Define labels
    plt.xlabel('x1')    
    plt.ylabel('x2')
## Legend will show the labels and associated colors
plt.legend()
## Show figure
plt.show()
```